# App script accessing secret manager to retrieve api token

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-secret-manager

I am trying to access secret manager from a small script I built on app script. I need to access and API with with a key but do not want to hardcode it.

I have already assigned the app to a project. I am just not sure how to query the token.

Answer (score 2):

To access the cloud Secrets manager, you'll need

- Change your project from the default apps Script one to a cloud platform project
- Turn on the secrets manager API in the cloud console
- Add oauth scopes in your manifest

  ```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ]
  ```
- IAM roles authorized with permission to access the Secrets manager. Here's how.

  https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/configuring-secret-manager
- Use the Apps Script auth token as Bearer in UrlFetchApp access to the secret manager endpoint.

Here's a write up on accessing secret manager from Apps Script, as well as a library you can use to do it for you.
https://ramblings.mcpher.com/apps-script/superfetch-proxy/superfetch-plugin-cloud-manager-secrets-and-apps-script/